# Offline mathjax For react native ios

Tags: ios, react-native, mathjax

I am using webview to render math content by linking mathjax cdn in react native . But how to approach the problem of making it offline.

1. Is there a way to locally maintain that bundle?
2. Is it even preferred?
3. What will be the size of the bundle ? I dont want my app size to go beyond 10mb.